# Spring Security with OAuth2 and anonymous access

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have my Spring REST API secured with Spring Security and OAuth2, I can successfully retrieve a token and access my APIs. My App defines the OAuth2 client itsself.

Now I want users to have anonymous access on some resources. The use case is really simple: *I want my app to be usable without login - but if they are logged in, I want to have access to that principal*.

Here is my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` so far:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/api1").anonymous().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ap2**").permitAll();
}
```

As soon as I add a second antMatcher/anonymous, it fails to work though, and it doesn't really express my intent either - e.g. I wan't to have anonymous access on `api1` GETs, but authenticated on POSTs (easy to do with `@PreAuthorize`).

How can I make the OAuth2 authentication optional?

Answer (score 0):

I dropped my `@EnableWebSecurity` and used a `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/api1", "/api/api2").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("my-resource-id");
    }
}
```

`/api/api1` may now be called with or without authentication.